# How to follow a user using Tweepy 4.0?

Tags: python, tweepy

This should hopefully be a pretty quick one but I can't seem to work it out myself.  I am now using the latest version of the twitter API and the old follow code:

api.create_friendship(name)

...is no longer working.  Just wondering what is the new syntax for the latest version of it is.

The entire code is:

```
import tweepy
from time import sleep
from random import randint

consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

class StreamCollector(tweepy.Stream):

    def on_status(self, status):
        try:
            name = status.user.screen_name
            sleep(randint(2, 39))
            print(name)
            tweetid = status.id
            print(tweetid)
            msg = """
https://twitter.com/necksaviorAU/status/1507929673728413706
"""
            print(status.text)
            sleep(randint(4, 45))
            api.update_status(status=msg, in_reply_to_status_id=status.id,
                              auto_populate_reply_metadata=True)

            api.create_friendship(name)

        except tweepy.error.TweepError as e:
            print(e)

stream = StreamCollector(consumer_key, consumer_secret,
    access_token, access_token_secret)

stream.filter(track=['Neck pain', 'sore neck', 'shoulder pain'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The `screen_name` parameter for [`API.create_friendship`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.0.0/api.html#tweepy.API.create_friendship) was changed to be a keyword-only argument in [Tweepy v4.0.0](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/releases/tag/v4.0.0).

Comment: stream.filter(follow = name, track=['Neck pain', 'sore neck', 'shoulder pain'])

Comment: Is is something like the above?  It is saying that 'name' is not defined where I have defined it above.  Sorry a bit of a python noob.

Comment: That's not related to `API.create_friendship` or following a user on Twitter, but you can follow a user for the stream that way if you define `name`, yes.

Comment: Sorry but how do I do it for the apei.create_friendship endpoint?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.